# How to find laplace transform of $\,\sinh(ct)\int_a^te^{au}\sinh(bu)\,du$

Tags: laplace-transform

How to find laplace transform of $$\sinh(ct)\int_a^te^{au}\sinh(bu)\,du.$$

I tried to integrate inner function and then do it, but it became way more tedious. So I was thinking there should be good way out for this. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
 &\mathcal{L}\left( \sinh(ct) \int_a^te^{au}\sinh(bu)\,\text{d}u \right)\\
=&\,\mathcal{L}\left(
  \sinh(ct)
  \frac
   {e^{a^2} (b \cosh(ab) - a\sinh(ab)) + e^{at} (a\sinh(bt) - b\cosh(bt))}
   {(a-b)(a+b)}
 \right) \\
=&\,\mathcal{L}\Bigg(
        -\frac{a e^{a^2} \sinh(ab) \sinh(ct)}{(a-b)(a+b)}
        +\frac{e^{a^2} b \cosh(ab) \sinh(ct)}{(a-b)(a+b)} \\
 &\qquad+\frac{a e^{at} \sinh(bt) \sinh(ct)}{(a-b)(a+b)}
        -\frac{b e^{at} \cosh(bt) \sinh(ct)}{(a-b)(a+b)}
  \Bigg)\\
=&\,-\frac{a e^{a^2} \sinh(ab)}{(a-b)(a+b)}
     \frac{c}{s^2-c^2}+\frac{e^{a^2} b \cosh(ab)}{(a-b)(a+b)}
     \frac{c}{s^2-c^2}\\
 &\,+\frac{a e^{at}}{(a-b)(a+b)}
     \frac{2 b c s}
          {b^4 - 2b^2 \left( c^2+s^2 \right) + \left(c^2-s^2\right)^2}\\
 &\,-\frac{b e^{at}}{(a-b)(a+b)}
     \frac{1}{4}
     \left(
       \frac{1}{-b-c+s}
      +\frac{1}{b-c+s}
      -\frac{1}{b+c+s}
      +\frac{1}{b-c-s}
     \right)
\end{align}